# clearInterval() not stoping setInterval() javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to stop my `setInterval()` but nothing I tried has worked.

what do I need to put in my `clearInterval` to stop the `setInterval()` function from running.

**html**

```
<p>PLease enter a time(secs) interval to have the divs change colors.</p>
Interval: <input type='number' id='interval' min='1' required>
<input type='button' value='Set Time' onclick='setTime()'>
<br><br>
<p> click the button below to stop it.</p>
<button onclick="clearInterval(x)">Stop it</button>
```

**javascript**

```
function setTime(){
    var userTime = document.getElementById('interval').value * 1000;

    if (userTime != null && userTime > 0 ){
        var x = setInterval(colorChangeTime, userTime);
    } else {
        alert("Please enter a number"); 
    }
```

the only thing I get with `clearInterval(x)` is a console error "x is undefined". I have tried other various things but haven't gotten anything to work.

Comment: `x` is _local_ variable of `setTime`, not accessible from outside of `setTime()`

Comment: here's a little more about @Tushar's comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript And note that `setTime()` doesn't have a closing brace in the code you provided, which might just be an omission in the question.

Comment: By making `x` _global_, [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/9w7o62L6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving the interval value in a local variable, thus it is not available outside the function.  If you want it available in some other function so you can call `clearInterval()`, then you need to save it somewhere where it will be available, not in a local variable.  Those options include a higher scoped, common variable, a property of some persistent object, etc...

For example:

```
var interval;
function setTime(){
    var userTime = document.getElementById('interval').value * 1000;

    if (userTime != null && userTime > 0 ){
        interval = setInterval(colorChangeTime, userTime);
    } else {
        alert("Please enter a number"); 
    }
}

function clearTime() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```